# Android: make immediate calls

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to write an app that, among other things, calls people. To do this, I use the following code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

The problem is: When I run it, it shows me a dialog and I need to choose with which app I want to make the call (Skype/Viber/Dialer/etc.). How can I make the call immediately using the **standard dialer** (without the dialog showing up)?

Comment: What makes you think that the user actually wants to place the call that way?

Comment: Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); try this.

Comment: @CommonsWare it's just for my app.

Comment: @Ali this give me the same results

Comment: What makes you think that the user actually wants to place the call that way in your app> For example, many people, myself included, use VOIP for placing outgoing calls, particularly in places where it would be less expensive than using mobile minutes. What you are saying is that, in your app, we are not allowed to use VOIP, but *must* use whatever you consider "the standard dialer" to be. Also, what do you plan to do on devices that do not have whatever you consider "the standard dialer" to be, but are capable of placing phone calls (SIP, Skype, etc.)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I agree, BUT in my case, the user already chose which app to make the call with on other situation. Here I just want to do the actual call (if he chose the standard dialer).

Comment: "the user already chose which app to make the call with on other situation" -- then you should not have to ask your question of how to place a phone call using the user's chosen option. What you should be doing is using `queryIntentActivities()` on your `ACTION_CALL` `Intent` to determine what "dialers" are possible, and using that to allow the user to "chose which app to make the call with". Not only would this give you the information with which to place the call with that "dialer", but it would allow the user to choose SIP, Skype, etc. if the user wants.

Comment: @CommonsWare What I want to do is that i'll be able to make phone calls from my computer (or other device) via my cellphone. I don't want to have to "touch" my cellphone at all. So I choose on my computer (Say on Windows Form) which number to call and which app to use, and all that the cellphone does is to make the call (without any pop-ups).

Comment: Then you need to do what I outlined in my previous comment, to allow the *user* to "chose which app to make the call with". You are welcome to store this information, then use it at the time of the call to use whichever "dialer" the user chose previously.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` and `Intent.ACTION_CALL` is that the first one allows the user to explicitly initiate the call showing the dialer UI. When using `ACTION_CALL`, a pop-up will open and let you choose which dialer to use.

Also, add permission on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: But if I don't want the user to choose which dialer to use?
I want to use only the standard dialer...

Comment: Have you set <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />  on your Intent Filter? (AndroidManifest)